# When did ATA introduce ATA Chapters?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance

When did ATA introduce the ATA chapters and since when was it used by all manufacturers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ATA100 was introduced as a publications standard in the late 50s for manuals and was in wide use by the late 60s.  Some manufacturers organized their engineering drawing numbering systems around ATA100 (ex.: flight control systems drawings numbered with a "27" or landing gear with a "32" prefix), but not all.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you maybe have a source where I can find more information?